# Aligning two images, one with border and one without

Tags: minipage, includegraphics, fbox

I want to align two images using `\minipage`. One of the images has already some sort of border on its own. To the second image i'd like to add one, using `\fbox`.
Without the border from `\fbox` the two images are aligned perfectly, but as soon as I add the frame, the image to which I added the box gets larger and isn't aligned properly anymore to the first image.

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering
    \minipage[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{PBC.png}
        \caption{Illustration der periodischen Randbedingungen}
        \label{fig:PBC}
    \endminipage\hfill
    \minipage[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{minimage.png}}
        \caption{Illustration der minimum image convention}
        \label{fig:minim}\hfill
    \endminipage
\end{figure}
```

And the output looks like this

[image]

As you can see, the image on the right, to which I added the border is very slightly larger than the first one, but I want them to be the same size.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Maybe make the image on the right a bit smaller with `\includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]`?

Comment: try: `width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule` for the second image.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both of your suggestions seem to work for me.